# Where do the schematic files go?

Tags: mcedit

I can't find where it is! I just saved it and it says `PandaCraft saved`. Where do the .schematic files save to?

Comment: Are you playing with mods, or just running MCEdit? MCEdit is a 3rd party program, not a mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the name of the file was `PandaCraft.schematic`. The way to find it is to hold down the Windows key, and press R. In the dialogue box, type `C:\`. When the window pops up, in the search bar, located in the top right hand corner, search `PandaCraft.schematic`. The search process may take a few minutes, depending on the size and availability of your hard drive. The result should pop up when the search is complete. If this does not work, instead search `*.schematic.` Find the file in the list, right click it, and click "Open File Location." The file will then be highlighted in it's containing folder in the File Explorer window. By the way, please do not post questions for technical support pertaining to modded games. It is considered off-topic. I hope you found this answer useful.